# If $f(x)=mx+n$, $g(x)=\sin(x)$ and $f[g(x)]=g[f(x)]$, then what is the value of $m⋅n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

**My problem**

> The functions f and g are defined by $f(x)=mx+n$ and $g(x)=\sin(x)$. If $f[g(x)]=g[f(x)]$, then the value of $m \cdot n$ is:
>
> - $-1$
> - $0$
> - $1$
> - $2$

**My attempt**

$$ \begin{align*}
  f[g(x)]&=g[f(x)]\\m\cdot \sin(x)+n&=\sin(mx+n)\\m \cdot n\cdot\sin(x)+n^2&=n\cdot\sin(mx+n)\\m\cdot n&=\dfrac{n\cdot\sin(mx+n)-n^2}{\sin(x)}\end{align*}
$$

That makes sense? I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Is $f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$ assumed to be true for all real $x$ or for only some $x$? In the first case, what can you conclude from substituting $x = 0$?

Comment: It is for all real numbers. I get it now. Thank you, @shoteyes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluating in $x=0$ you get
$$f(g(0))=g(f(0))$$
hence
$$f(0)=g(n)\Rightarrow n=\sin(n)$$
Assuming $m,n\in\mathbb{R}$
$$|n|=|\sin(n)|\leq 1$$
and you easily find that the only possibility is $n=0,$ hence $mn=0.$